# Gamma correction in Y'CbCr space

Tags: image-processing, yuv, color-space, gamma

I need to do gamma correction on images in Y'CbCr space so I can bring out details in saturated and starved areas in an image and I'm wondering if I need to adjust the chroma sub channels?

I know that if I starve the luma channel pixels the chroma will bleed through if I don't adjust it. Do I need to make the same considerations when doing gamma correction? Is it worth the effort to adjust the chroma channels?

Comment: It seems you can bring out a lot of information in the dark areas of the images by boosting the chroma channels, but you only want to do this in the dark parts of the image. Either way, editing colors in Y'CbCr should be done carefully. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do the lum channel.
It probably has less color shift effect than doing gamma on R,G,B separatly which is what most display do